# Dalvik message - Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required

Tags: android

When I used BufferedInputStream and I specify a buffer size, Dalvik gives me this warning - Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.

But right now, my buffer size is already at 8k. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Just use:**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8192);
```

**instead of:**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

**Note:**

8192 (8k) is the size of the buffer in characters.

Comment: I used `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8192);` but still I am getting same message

Answer (score 11):

You're not doing anything wrong. It's just informing you that you chose the version of the BufferedInputStream that doesn't take the size argument. If you use the other one (`BufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size)`), then you can specify your own buffer size.

You can choose to ignore the warning if 8KB happens to be exactly what you need, or you can adjust the size with the constructor to tailor it to your needs - as small as possible, as big as necessary.

Comment: This is correct, but the warning is an indication that the Android framework devs would still prefer that an explicit size request be made rather than relying on the default. From comments in the source, "we want to discourage the use of this constructor".  Though, as you say, if an 8K buffer is specified explicitly, there's absolutely no difference in behavior (other than getting no warning logged).

Comment: The log definitely is a difference in behavior, and results in temporary strings being created and such.  Just always use the constructor with an explicit size.  That's the desired behavior.

Comment: So do the framework devs recommend another size, or a way to determine your need?

Comment: It's entirely up to you. If you read a file that never exceeds 1KB in size, set your buffer to 1KB. If you read something that has huge lines, set it to something higher. There is no one-size-fits-all size. 8KB is simply a default value that works reasonably well in most cases, but your case may be different. And, more importantly, like Dianne said - even if you want to stay at 8KB, you should specify a value. That way, you avoid the log output, which is just wasted overhead.

Comment: for BufferedInputStream(URLConnection.openConnection().getInputStream()) is 8KB a good size ? or shall I make it smaller ?