# It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required. [ERROR]

Tags: android, listview, logcat

I'm developing a `ListView` that shows data from mysql database, but I am getting the following error in logcat:

It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the line in logcat:

`07-16 03:49:16.388: I/global(391): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.`

My Java Code

```
package com.database_demo;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Database_demo extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{

    //http post
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.2");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    //Convert response to string  
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

      sb = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      is.close();

      result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //END Convert response to string   
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               r.add(json_data.getString("category"));
           }
           setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, r));
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
}
```

nullpointer exeption

```
07-16 04:02:28.708: D/AndroidRuntime(417): Shutting down VM
07-16 04:02:28.708: W/dalvikvm(417): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.database_demo/com.database_demo.Database_demo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at com.database_demo.Database_demo.onCreate(Database_demo.java:78)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this line from:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
```

to this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"), 8192);
```

It should remove that message

Comment: tanx but another error came out the logcat says `07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.database_demo/com.database_demo.Database_demo}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: We are going to need to see the whole stacktrace.  NullPointerException can occur anywhere

Comment: theres the  whole logcat for the nullexpetion above..can you see it for me?

Comment: Your problem is occuring within the JSON portion but I cannot pinpoint it.  Can you tell me what is at line 78 within Database_demo.java

Comment: `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);`

thats the line 78

Comment: You need to dubug to see if anything is being returned within result from the inputstream. it will error out on this constructor if the string does not begin with [ and end with ]  http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the result of your page is too long:

Use:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8192);
```

instead of

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
```

[Dalvik message - Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498643/dalvik-message-default-buffer-size-used-in-bufferedinputstream-constructor-it)

Comment: another error came out the logcat says `07-16 04:02:28.728: E/AndroidRuntime(417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.database_demo/com.database_demo.Database_demo}: java.lang.NullPointerException`